# PHP Java Bridge: ClassDefNotFound error

Tags: java, php, runtime-error, php-java-bridge

currently I am working with PHP Java Bridge. I am following [this](https://phpcoderblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/php-java-run-java-from-php-tutorial-how-to-run-java-code-from-php-use-java-in-php-java-php-php-to-java-tutorial/) tutorial to make php run java code. But I don't know why, after I followed that instruction, I got this error: [image]

Anyone have an idea about what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: check for .class files

Comment: the .class file is there. And also I have tried to add it to the class path environment, but it still not working.